# PHP function returning boolean

Tags: php, boolean

How can I have a `boolean` returning function?
I mean like this on other programming language.

```
return true; // return false
```

Comment: that's exactly how you do it in PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question does not entirely make sense, because you have not asked something you've already solved.

The function in PHP can be done like this.

```
function check($int) {
   if ($int == 3) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
if (check(3)) echo "Returned true!";
```

Comment: Can I also check in the if isset($int)? And instead of 3, another parameter named $length?

Comment: @Cyril - you can check whatever you want... you just need to code the function to do that check... I suggest you read the relevant section of the PHP documentation on functions http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if it was return ($int == 3);

Comment: @AntonioCS Yes, that would be a more ideal way to go about things but keep in mind that's a little more advanced and should not be demonstrated to beginners without a grasp of the fundamentals.

That's correct completely though and personally I do it that way too if I am doing a compare. :)

Comment: Thanks (: I'm a Obj-C developer PHP is quite lot of magic for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Incredibly enough

```
return true;
```

e.g.

```
function testIfABC($x) {
    if ($x === 'ABC') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

though that could more easily be written as:

```
function testIfABC($x) {
    return ($x === 'ABC');
}
```

which will still return a boolean value

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

  function doSomething() {
    return true;
  }
```

The function you need could look like this:

```
  function check($var, $length) { 
    return (strlen($var)<=$length) && (isset($var));
  }

?>
```

Comment: Strange, I have this function function check($var, $length) { if((strlen(var)<=$length) && (isset($var))) { return true; } else { return false; } }. The function checks whether there's a value on $var and if the strlen()<=$length... When running I get an error on the if line.

Comment: Probably "strlen($var)" instead of "strlen(var)" ?

Answer (score 2):

As a more practical example, you can use any boolean expression as result:

```
return ($data != "expected") or ($param == 17);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.5 you can use the [`boolval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php) function:

> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)
>   boolval — Get the boolean value of a variable

```
return boolval( $result );
```

Or just [convert to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). But perhaps all this is not necessary:

> To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the `(bool)` or `(boolean)` casts. However, in most cases the cast is unnecessary, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires a boolean argument.

```
return (bool) $result;
return (boolean) $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

I do understand the question, as in visual C# you can define a function to return bool only. This is not the case in PHP. You can just use function blabla($val) { return ($val == "yes" ? true : false); }. No support for "public bool($value) { return true; // false }"